# File is found even though folder is empty using bash - test whether a directory is empty

Tags: bash, file, glob

I want to see if files exist in a certain folder and if they exist run certain event else skip this. Bash see files in my empty folder.

I tried a few different ways and all show that a file exits.

```
$ [ -f ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
Found
$ [ -r ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
Found
$ [ -e ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"
Found
```

Whereas it does not:

```
$ ls -lrt
total 0
```

What am I missing here?

My actual code is:

```
get_last_parsed_file_time ()
{
if [ -s "$DATA_DIR$EPG_XML_FILES" ]
then
    NEWEST_FILE=$( ls -tr | tail -1 )
    LAST_PARSED_TIME=$( stat -c %Y $NEWEST_FILE )
else
    NO_FILE=1
fi 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`[ -f filename ]` checks if `filename` is a file that exists.

`[ str ]` checks whether `str` is non-empty.

In your case, `str` is `-f`, but it still just checks whether *string* `"-f"` is nonempty, which it obviously isn't (it's two characters, a dash and an `"f"`).

This is especially puzzling in the case of `[ -f $filename ]`. When `$filename` is empty and unquoted, the command will become `[ -f ]` and will be true. Always quote your variables.

Comment: Alternatively, use the (in bash) preferred form `[[ ... ]]`, then quoting your variable references is optional.

Comment: For the most part, anyways. Unquoted, `[[ $x == $x ]]` is false if `x='[wtf]'`

Comment: Thanks - didn't know that; what explains this unexpected behavior?

Comment: I understand -f, is it true for others too? like r/s/e?

Comment: @user3339249: Yes, the same logic applies to _all_ file operators (such as the ones you mention).

Comment: so there is no way to check a directory by a simple `if [[ -e "$DATA_DIR$EPG_XML_FILES" ]]`

Comment: @utamav: You can check for the *directory's* existence that way (though to ensure that it's actually a _directory_, use `-d`), but it won't tell you if the directory is empty or not.

Comment: @mklement0 == matches a pattern, not a string. When quoting the right hand side, it's considered a literal instead of a glob.

Comment: So the take-home lesson seems to be: (a) use `[[ ... ]]` over `[ ... ]` to get more features and predictability (b) if you use variable references as the _right_ operand that you wish to be interpreted as literals, double-quote them. It is safe to double-quote _both_ operands if you wish them to be interpreted as literals.

Comment: @utamav: To be clearer: no, you canNOT combine globs (filename patterns such as `*`) with the file operators such as `-f` - they only take a _single, literal_ filename/path argument that (whether as a string literal or variable reference).

Answer (score 0):

[that other guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21947054/45375) explains why `[ -f ]` doesn't work.

More generally, it is important to note that **you cannot pass globs (filename *patterns* such as `*` to a bash file-test operator such as `-f`.** The file-test operators expect a **single, literal** filename or file path (either as a string literal or as a string stored in a variable).

```
[[ -f '/path/to/file' ]] # correct
[[ -f /path/to/* ]]      # WRONG
```

Here's a snippet that **tests whether a folder is empty**, i.e. whether it contains ANY items -  whether files, hidden files, or subfolders:

```
folder='/path/to/folder'
[[ -n $(ls -A "$folder" | head -n 1) ]] && echo "NON-empty" || echo "EMPTY"
```

- To only consider non-hidden items, remove `-A` from the `ls` command.
- To quietly ignore the case where the input folder doesn't exist or is not accessible, append `2> /dev/null` to the `ls` command.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to check most of that stuff as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @utamav: Substantially revised my answer to be more helpful, hopefully.